# Google Static Maps, draw custom route direction

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-static-api

I have a React app that makes an API call to the Google Static Maps service, to get a map.

I'm wondering if it's possible to draw a custom direction line between two geolocations. Currently, I'm drawing that line but it looks... ugly:

[image]

What I would like is a curved line, with a plane icon, just like this:

[image]

Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Static Maps API allows to draw geodesic lines

> **geodesic**: (optional) indicates that the requested path should be interpreted as a geodesic line that follows the curvature of the earth. When false, the path is rendered as a straight line in screen space. Defaults to false.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#Paths

Add this option to your path parameter. Additionally you can add a custom plane icon that overlaps the geodesic path.

For example,

`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x400&path=weight%3A5%7Ccolor%3A0x111111%7Cgeodesic%3Atrue%7CAmsterdam%7CTashkent&markers=icon%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fcdn0.iconfinder.com%2Fdata%2Ficons%2Fshopping-and-e-commerce-2%2F400%2FCargo_plane_icon-64.png%7C47.557774%2C43.044347&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Run the following code snippet to see it in action

```html
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=600x400&path=weight%3A5%7Ccolor%3A0x111111%7Cgeodesic%3Atrue%7CAmsterdam%7CTashkent&markers=icon%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fcdn0.iconfinder.com%2Fdata%2Ficons%2Fshopping-and-e-commerce-2%2F400%2FCargo_plane_icon-64.png%7C47.557774%2C43.044347&key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&signature=Y-EtK76SDUyAao0uuGniNx3LhWs="
  title="sample geodesic path" />
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: how did you convert the url of the png with all the %2F etc .. ?

Comment: This is described in the documentation: "Specify the icon using a URL (which should be URL-encoded). You can use URLs created by URL-shortening services such as https://goo.gl. Most URL-shortening services have the advantage of automatically encoding URLs". Just apply URL encoding. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro#CustomIcons